# Why does the onbegin function for my SVG animate element start inconsistently, and often much later than expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, linear-gradients, svg-animate

I have this code where I am attempting to begin a linear gradient animation, and add a CSS blur-in effect to the parent SVG at the same time:

```
    $("#hero video").on("loadeddata", function(){

        function startBlur(){
                
            var blurParameters = {"-webkit-animation":"blur 3.75s","animation":"blur 4s","-webkit-animation-fill-mode":"forwards","animation-fill-mode":"forwards"};

            setTimeout(function(){

                $("#title").css(blurParameters);

            }, 1000);
        }

        document.querySelector("#title animate").setAttributeNS(null,"onbegin",startBlur());

        document.querySelector("#title animate").beginElement();
            
    });
```

Sometimes it works perfectly, but the linear gradient animation I'm attempting to start with `beginElement` appears very inconsistent, and frequently occurs a couple of seconds *after* the CSS blur (the blur seems to always happen on time). I added a timeout on the blur hoping that if the SVG animation started first it would at least look like they were starting at the same time, but it still doesn't work. I've console logged when beginElement happens, and it will log that it's started well before the animation visibly begins.

SVGs aren't an area of expertise for me. What am I doing wrong that it's taking so much longer to start the animation?

Edit:

Here's the markup for the gradient:

```
<linearGradient id="title-gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#cfc09f"/>
    <stop offset="3%" stop-color="#634f2c"/>
    <stop offset="18%" stop-color="#cfc09f"/>
    <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#cfc09f"/>
    <stop offset="45%" stop-color="#ffecb3"/>
    <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#3a2c0f"/>
    <animate id="title-animation" values=".25;1" attributeName="y2" dur="9000ms" begin="indefinite"/>
</linearGradient>
```

I've found that wrapping what I wrote in `$(window).on("load")` fixes the issue, but am still curious why it doesn't work by itself and would like to not have to wait for everything on the page to load before starting the animation.

Comment: What does the markup for the `<animate>` element look like?

Comment: @ccprog sure, it's `<animate id="title-animation" values=".25;1" attributeName="y2" dur="9000ms" begin="indefinite"/>`

Comment: I also found that wrapping the function in $(window).on("load") fixed the issue. I'll edit my original question to reflect this; am still curious why the code doesn't work without it.